# Webkit (inside titanium desktop) shrinked fonts

Tags: html, css, fonts, webkit, titanium

This problem appears on every bit of text, no matter if it is table,div or something else

As you can see on every right side of text elements, 1-2 pixels is missing. Adding of padding never helps

Any suggestions please?[image]

Comment: What HTML and CSS generates this appearance?  Show us your code.

Comment: By "Titanium Desktop", do you mean the [application development environment from Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-desktop-application-development/)? Your question would be even stronger if it clearly described the context.

Comment: Titanium desktop = Desktop application build with titanium studio, it has embedded webkit and uses pure html/css. According the code, it happens on plain span, with no css. So if i'd say <span>anything</span> this will be the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to following fix for webkit browsers.
Replace the button span with your text class..

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { /* Safari and
Google Chrome only - fix margins */ your classname { margin-top: –1px;
} }

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the viewport meta tag to specify its width and zoom scale? Maybe that would help? It's documented in the [Apple dev docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008193-SW6)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using -webkit-font-size-adjust.

Look here for more info on it:

http://webdesignernotebook.com/css/the-little-known-font-size-adjust-css3-property/

Answer (score 0):

This is happening probably because of

1. Inherited CSS property
2. If CSS does not seem to fixed it, check [html doctype](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp). Some tags although in rare cases do not work with certain doc types.
3. use !important attribute in CSS to enforce a certain rule be applied which discards all others.

Comment: as i already noticed, this happens on clear html file with just one span, with no css at all, tryed everything suggested in this question. Every user i distributed programm to has same problem. Doctype of html5 specified... Tryed reset, tryed everything. Interesting if installation of titanium studio on other windows machine will lead to same behaviour. There just must be some common css reset, but tryed all what i found and what was suggested over here...

Answer (score 0):

try to set `display: inline-block` and a negative `text-indent` to `<span>` elements (embedded inside a webkit-only media query)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to deal with this problem for a month. Here what I have tried and found out. But I could not get actual solution;

I have followed up this thread, unfortunately nothing worked.

Tried several simple html documents with most possible doctypes,css,font-size,font-styles reset ..etc did not worked.

I discovered; when using with a remote url, it seems work fine, rendering is ok. When using embedded html pages, causing the problem.

In Titanium issue list; I have found out that, they represented as a Webkit bug.
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIDESK-136

Solution might be upgrading webkit version but Titanium has a lot functionality over webkit. So upgrading would not be an easy task.

Comment: Thank you for your response, at least i know that i am not alone with this issue :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem in TideSDK in windows was to do the following on the font in question:

```
font-weight: 600;
```

Maybe not the best solution for your application, (maybe you don't want to add any space or weight to the font since it seems you may have a much larger table of data to display) , but acceptable by my client.