# TideSDK / Titanium Desktop Font Issue on Windows

Tags: windows, fonts, webkit, titanium, tidesdk

I have an issue with both Titanium desktop and TideSDK. The issue is explained here

[Webkit (inside titanium desktop) shrinked fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961880/webkit-inside-titanium-desktop-shrinked-fonts)

and reported as a "fixed" bug here
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIDESK-136

To quickly summerize, the issue involves the last 1px column of the last font being cut off.

The case shows it resolved but its happening to me on both windows 7 and windows xp. I figured it was due to the outdated webkit but I just found wunderlist which is built on this but appears not to be affected.

Has anyone experienced this and if so fixed it?

Currently I am using TideSDK v1.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Use `-webkit-font-size-adjust` and that should fix the problem.

Comment: To what and what amount? I have tried setting it to 100% and 1 and to the body and to the elements I have seen with the issue on and to all elements and it does not seem to affect it. When I check out the inspector it does not show that setting applied

Comment: Specifically I use `-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;` and the inspector may not always show it since it is WebKit only. Try running in your iOS sim then clicking "Develop->iPhone Simulator" in Safari and that will help you debug.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy replies. I originally has that and it does not help. I have applied it to html, body and even *. 

I dont have the iphone sim (windows only here) but have tested in in Chrome and it renders great there. It's only crappy in the app version. Some elements I have added a space which fixes it but it's not an option for inputs and such.